# Is it possible to delay uglifyjs plugin execution?

Tags: webpack

We are writing a plugin in webpack for customization. When we add the plugin to webpack config, it is causing the uglify js plugin to run (in production mode) before the plugin we have. Is it possible to defer the uglify js plugin execution after our customized plugin execution?. please share your suggestions.